VB6 normal text search finds special characters
Odd things started happening with text searches, both in code and in the IDE.  I have to maintain a legacy app written in VB6, making minor changes every now and then.  In the last week something changed (nothing was added or removed in the environment**) that causes text searches to find special/html/foreign characters.
For example, in the IDE find box, if I search for "ss", it will highlight "ß".
The same things happens in code when using the Replace function and vbTextCompare compare method.  Other examples, like "th" will find "þ", etc.
This particular app has code that translates html codes to their character equivalent and back.  It has a Dictionary of values and simply loops the items to create an HTML safe text, but now ends up changing words like "Process" to "Proceß".  Everything has been great until the most recent build, which caused the above issues.  I'm especially perplexed as to why this happens in the IDE.
And this happens in all projects, even a new one without any outside modules.  So I have to assume it's something in the IDE or main options, but I can't find what that could be.
Has anyone seen this before?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.
** This is on my development desktop (Windows 11) so I'm the only one who uses it, and except for Windows Updates, nothing has changed in the last few months.  Especially not in VB6.



Probably a system setting. see (for example) the accepted answer at ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123029/ ) which uses a string test example which includes system culture info specifically comparing "th" with "thorn". This would account for it occuring in VB6 search boxes

Thanks for the example.  I'm just wondering what might have changed in the week since the last build.  If it's a system thing, and not specific to VB6, why wasn't it an issue before?  Guess I'll keep digging.
